# Discrete mathematics (Congruence Modulo)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Can someone please help me solving the below stated problem? 
$$ 5^{25}+25^5  \pmod {23}$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the difficulty?  note that $23$ is prime so $x^{23}\equiv x\pmod {23}$.

Comment: Do you know about Fermat's Little Theorem? That will help.

Comment: @SalmanRahman How did you get to the answer? Mathematics is about the process, not the result.

Comment: @SalmanRahman Google will give you many results for modulo arithmetic calculators if you just want to verify your answer. Understanding why this can be done easily by hand is something different however and I expect that's the point of this exercise.

Answer (score 1):

$$\quad{5^{25}+25^5\equiv5^{25}+
(23+2)^5  \pmod {23}\\\equiv5^{25}+
(0+2)^5  \pmod {23}
\\\equiv5^{25}+32 \pmod {23}\\\equiv5^{25}+32-23 \pmod {23}\\\equiv5^{25}+9\pmod {23}}$$ now use  $\phi$ $$\quad{5^{\phi(23)}\equiv 1 \pmod {23}\\
5^{23(1-\frac1{23})}\equiv 1 \pmod {23}\\
5^{22}\equiv 1 \pmod {23}\\\times 5^3\\5^{22+3}\equiv 1\times5^3 \pmod {23}\\5^{25}\equiv 125 \pmod {23}\\5^{25}\equiv 125-5(23) \pmod {23}\\5^{25}\equiv 10 \pmod {23}\\}$$ put it into above result
$$\quad{5^{25}+25^5\equiv5^{25}+9\pmod {23}\\\equiv10+9\pmod {23}\\\equiv19\pmod {23}}\\$$

Answer (score 0):

Because $23$ is prime, by [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem),
$$5^{23-1}=5^{22}\equiv 1\mod{23}$$

So $$\begin{align}5^{22}&\equiv 1&\mod23 \\ 5^{22}\times5^3&\equiv1\times5^3&\mod23 \\5^{25}&\equiv125&\mod23 \\&\equiv10&\mod23 \end{align}$$
Note that $$25^1\equiv2\mod23$$which means $$\begin{align}25^1\times25^5&\equiv 2^5&\mod23 \\ 25^5&\equiv32&\mod23 \\&\equiv11 &\mod 9\end{align}$$

So $$5^{25}+25^5\equiv10+9\equiv19\mod23$$

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of ways to reduce these but I'm not sure whether or not you've ever heard of "Fermat's Little Theorem" so I will avoid using it.

First, observe that $25 \equiv 2 \pmod{23}$ and so, $25^5 \equiv 2^5 \equiv 9 \pmod{23}$.

Moreover, note that $25^5 = 5^{10}$. This implies that $$5^{25} \equiv (5^{10})^2(5^5) \equiv (9^2)(5)(5^4) \equiv 12 \cdot 5 \cdot (5^2)^2 \equiv 60 \cdot 2^2 \equiv 14 \cdot 4 \equiv 28 \cdot 2 \equiv 5 \cdot 2 \equiv 10 \pmod{23}.$$

Adding the two together yields $$19\pmod{23}.$$